# This class may not be available in this context error XCODE?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile, uikit

Hi everyone my xcode dont see any UIKit elements also dont see even UIKit itself.Help me plz ı use Xcode Version 13.2.1 ı share images so you easily see errors [Cant See UIKit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUqsJ.png)  /
[Cant see UIKit elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn8kO.png)

Answer (score -1):

I found solution.
I changed ALLOW_TARGET_PLATFORM_SPECIALIZATION = YES; to ALLOW_TARGET_PLATFORM_SPECIALIZATION = NO;
You cand find PROJECT/TARGETS/BUİLD SETTİNGS/Then you can find on Build Options part